# Hide an element that button is contained in using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, hide, show

So I have some tiles that are arranged using a list of UL and then several LI tags.

I want to have a button inside one of the LI tags that will hide the whole tile when pressed.

Not sure how to go about it. Something like - this.('li').hide() but i know thats wrong lol.

Many thanks.

```
 <ul class="sortable grid">
        <li>Item 1</li><button onclick="hidePane()">Dismiss</button>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>


 <script>


function hidePane(){

    this.hide();

}

 </script>
```

I want it to be dynamic. The intended use for this is to have a loop pulling in many tiles. So id like it to have a dismiss button on each and when clicked it will just hide tiles as you scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not  put elements outside `li`. In `ul`, first level elements inside should always be just `li`, so then inside the `li` you can put your button:

```js
$('.sortable button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('li').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable grid">
  <li>Item 1<button>Dismiss</button></li>
  <li>Item 2<button>Dismiss</button></li>
  <li>Item 3<button>Dismiss</button></li>
</ul>
```

A solution based on your code, using only `JavaScript` would imply to use `event.target` to get the current clicked button and its parent using `parentElement` and you would also use `style.display = none;` because there is no `hide()` method in pure `JavaScript`:

```js
function hidePane(event) {
  event.target.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<ul class="sortable grid">
  <li>Item 1<button onclick="hidePane(event)">Dismiss</button></li>
  <li>Item 2<button onclick="hidePane(event)">Dismiss</button></li>
  <li>Item 3<button onclick="hidePane(event)">Dismiss</button></li>
  <li>Item 4<button onclick="hidePane(event)">Dismiss</button></li>
  <li>Item 5<button onclick="hidePane(event)">Dismiss</button></li>
  <li>Item 6<button onclick="hidePane(event)">Dismiss</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @jord49, awesome. You're welcome. Happy to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

Html code:

```
<ul class="sortable grid">
    <li>Item 1 <br /><input type="submit" onclick="hidePane(this);"></li>
    <li>Item 2 <br /><input type="submit" onclick="hidePane(this);"></li>
    <li>Item 3 <br /><input type="submit" onclick="hidePane(this);"></li>
    <li>Item 4 <br /><input type="submit" onclick="hidePane(this);"></li>
    <li>Item 5 <br /><input type="submit" onclick="hidePane(this);"></li>
    <li>Item 6 <br /><input type="submit" onclick="hidePane(this);"></li>
</ul>
```

JS code:

```
  function hidePane(ref) {
                $(ref).parent().hide()
            }
```

Comment: Thank you @Adeel You are a life saver

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you do it by JQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable grid">
        <li>Item 1<button class="dismiss"> Dismiss</button></li>
        <li>Item 2<button class="dismiss"> Dismiss</button></li>
        <li>Item 3<button class="dismiss"> Dismiss</button></li>
        <li>Item 4<button class="dismiss"> Dismiss</button></li>
        <li>Item 5<button class="dismiss"> Dismiss</button></li>
        <li>Item 6<button class="dismiss"> Dismiss</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is your JS

```
$(".dismiss").click(function () {
 $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

I would recommend you to not to use html onclick() since it was considered a bad practice
[[Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice][1])

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery: select the item by the id and then use the hide method.

```
$('#id_of_li').hide();
```

Comment: Batter remove all :P

Comment: I want it to be dynamic though. The intended use for this is to have a loop pulling in many tiles. So id like it to have a dismiss button on each and when clicked it will just hide tiles as you scroll.

Comment: So you need a loop and set the id with the same in the li element and the button then you have to
$('#button_id').click(function() {
    $('#li_' + this.attr('id').split('_')[1]).hide()
})

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It allows you to hide the `li` containing the button.

```js
$("#hide").on('click',function(){

 hidePane($(this).parent());
});

function hidePane(parent){
  parent.hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable grid">
        <li>Item 1 <button id="hide">Dismiss</button></li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
```